# Como separar variable que trae números con comas en php

Tags: php

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php 

$conteo=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id_patendi, refe, reto, pos, COUNT(*) AS valore FROM p_atendidas WHERE refe='$elid' AND reto='SI'");
            while($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($conteo)){
                
                $total_pos=$cont['valore'];
                
                }

?>
```

Esta consulta actualmente me cuenta el total de registros que tengan el reto='SI'.
Por otro lado tengo la variable 'pos' esa variable trae un numero en especifico, lo que estoy buscando hacer es que me imprima en un input text esa variable pero separadas por comas, ejemplo:

1,2,3

```
<input type="text" class="camp" id="pos" name="pos" value="<?php echo $pos?>" readonly="readonly" />
```

El gran detalle es que no se como puedo hacerlo, otro ejemplo:

La consulta que tengo esta con un while para que de esta manera me traiga todos los registros que correspondan con la refe, puede traer 2 o 3 registros, la idea es poder separar por comas todos esos registros en un input.

De que forma podría hacerlo?

cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿los registros actualmente como están separados? ¿son un arreglo?

Comment: Asi es estan separados como un arreglo, estoy guardando en la base de datos en filas, son registros diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la función join(), de php en la cual como primer parámetro ingresas el elemento que quieras que unifique el arreglo y como segundo parámetro le pasas el arreglo. mencionar que, join() es un alias de la funcion implode(), siendo esta ultima la forma mas nativa de ejecutar la accion de unificar un arreglo, pero no existe diferencia de rendimiento ni nada, es exactamente lo mismo.

```
<?php
   $arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
   echo join(",",$arr); // Hello,World!,Beautiful,Day!
?>
```

Comment: aun no me funciona bien, lo hice de esta forma: en mi consulta dentro del while imprimí $pot=$cont['posatendi'];
    
    $arr = array($pot);  y luego en el boton colocoecho join(",",$arr);?> pero aun asi solo me trae un solo valor, deberia traer algo como: 1,2,3

Comment: ¿estas seguro de que $arr es un arreglo con todos los valores?, primero imprime $arr y ve que arroja.

Comment: Cuando imprimo $arr sale esto: Array

Comment: imprime $arr[0], luego $arr[1], si el segundo no te arroja nada, significa que tu arreglo solo tiene un elemento